# Create a Correlation Column in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to create a correlation column in R with a given amount of lag. 
Example:

Following are two data columns which I am trying to correlate against each other. I want the last 3 points of correlation, therefore the first two rows will be NA.

```
 Val1   Val2   Corr
  1      2      NA
  2      3      NA
  2      4     0.86
  4      5     0.86
  1      3     0.98
  3      2     0.5
  2      1    -0.5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the numbers above it seems that what u want is the rolling correlation with a 
window size of 3.

```
> cor(c(1,2,2),c(2,3,4))
[1] 0.8660254
> cor(c(2,4,1),c(4,5,3))
[1] 0.9819805
```

using the `RcppRoll` package u can do this:

```
require(RcppRoll)

test<-tibble(
  x=c(1,2,2,4,1,3,2),
  y=c(2,3,4,5,3,2,1),
  rcor=local({
    n<-3
    roll_cov <- (roll_meanr(x*y,n,fill=0)-roll_meanr(x,n,fill=0)*roll_meanr(y,n,fill=0))*n/(n-1)
    roll_cov/sqrt(roll_varr(x,n,fill=0)*roll_varr(y,n,fill=0))
  })
)
```

and this gives

```
> test
# A tibble: 7 x 3
      x     y    rcor
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     2 NaN    
2     2     3 NaN    
3     2     4   0.866
4     4     5   0.866
5     1     3   0.982
6     3     2   0.500
7     2     1  -0.5  
>
```